# How can I initialize an Ormlite foreigncollection without a dao

Tags: android, ormlite, foreign-collection

I have an object that has a `ForeignCollection`, when I first create the object *in memory* the collection is null. My question is can I *initialize* this `ForeignCollection` without the **dao** ? And if not, can I create a **dao** without a **connectionsource**??
I wanna achieve this in order to use the `foreigncollection` in *unit testing* which doesn't access the database and is all done in memory.